# Combine two objects as one with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a query object for mongoose, so

```
let countryCondition = {};
searchQuery = {
    "$text": {
        "$search": searchString
    }
};
query = {
    searchQuery,
    countryCondition
};
console.log('$query:', query);
```

When i **console.log** query, i see the ouput as,

```
$query: { 
    searchQuery: { 
        '$text': { 
            '$search': '2017' 
         } 
    },
    countryCondition: {} 
}
```

but i need

```
[{ '$text': { '$search': '2017' } }, {}]
```

Comment: maybe do you need `[{ '$text': { '$search': '2017' } }, {}]`?

Comment: @Slavik yes if its ok for mongodb

Answer (score 2):

As Slavik mentioned, you're probably looking for an array rather than an object:

```
[{ '$text': { '$search': '2017' } }, {}]
```

since objects must have names for their parameters.

Try this:

```
let query = [
  searchQuery,
  countryCondition
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to combine the objects in one use Object.assign

```js
let countryCondition = {
    country: 'Spain'
};

let searchQuery = {
    '$text': {
        '$search': 'sometext'
    }
};

let query = Object.assign(searchQuery, countryCondition);

console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'r looking for an or condition your object should be like

```
{ $or: [ { text: "search text" }, { country: "xyz" } ] }
```

If you'r looking for an and condition then you can combine two objects following Diego's answer

```
{text : {}, country : {}}
```

You can get the first object like

```
let query = {};
query['$or'] = [];

query['$or'].push({'text' : 'some text'});
query['$or'].push({'country' : 'xyz'});
```